# Rescaling the data points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, dataset

Lets say I have the following data points,

```
 data1 = {26.96930425, 26.94343471, 26.89912143, 26.84923793, 
 26.83813424, 26.78747592, 26.77180729, 26.7344019, 26.69865987, 
 26.67581011, 26.64927891}

data2 = {27.31813031, 27.2891453, 27.25729205, 27.28633558, 
27.28700594, 27.30034307, 27.27765688, 27.25401703, 27.26704573, 
27.27382588, 27.25844849, 27.2781408, 27.25090313, 27.24495574, 
27.22815005, 27.18166762}

a=ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}]
```

is there any way to reduce the length of data2 to length of data1 i.e. Length[data2]=Length[data1] while retaining the original shape of the plot of data2?

so at the end a=ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}] but within the same range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by adding x-coordinates with the same range for both plots:

```
dat1 = Transpose[{Range[Length[data1]], data1}];
dat2 = Transpose[{Range[1, 
     Length[data1], (Length[data1] - 1)/(Length[data2] - 1)], 
    data2}];
ListLinePlot[{dat1, dat2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way is

```
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2[[1 ;; Dimensions[data1][[1]]]]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are `TrimRight` and `TrimLeft` in the `GeneralUtilities` package

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

ListLinePlot[TrimRight[{data1, data2}], GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Using `DataRange`:**

```
data1 = {26.96930425, 26.94343471, 26.89912143, 26.84923793, 
   26.83813424, 26.78747592, 26.77180729, 26.7344019, 26.69865987, 
   26.67581011, 26.64927891};

data2 = {27.31813031, 27.2891453, 27.25729205, 27.28633558, 
   27.28700594, 27.30034307, 27.27765688, 27.25401703, 27.26704573, 
   27.27382588, 27.25844849, 27.2781408, 27.25090313, 27.24495574, 
   27.22815005, 27.18166762};
```

---

```
p0 = ListLinePlot[{data1, data1 + 0.04, data2, data2 + 0.04}
   , PlotRange -> {26, 28}
   , PlotStyle -> {Purple, Lighter@Purple, Brown, Lighter@Brown}
   ];
pout = ListLinePlot[data2, DataRange -> {1, Length@data1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotRange -> {26, 28}];

Show[p0, pout]
```

---

[image]